# How to add Emacs-style keybindings to a text box in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, qt6

I would like to create a text box which supports a few common keybindings from Emacs and Bash, such as:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> moves the cursor backwards by one character.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> moves the cursor backwards by one word, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> deletes the word to the right of the cursor, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> acts like <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What's the idiomatic way to do this in Qt 6? I can see that the `QLineEdit` class has `event` and `keyPressEvent` methods which can be overridden. Apparently, there's also an "event filter" mechanism that can be used to intercept key presses before they reach the text box. I would like to know which one of these methods is recommended for this purpose and won't cause problems later.

I'm using the old Widgets API rather than QML. Both C++ and Python answers are welcome.

Comment: It might make sense to do this with an event filter. You can maybe make it so, that you can apply the same filter to any QWidget, converting these keys to normal cursor movement keys. Maybe.

Comment: All QObjects have `event()`, and all widgets have `keyPressEvent()`, which is what `event()` calls in QWidgets when it receives a keyboard event. Event filtering may only be useful if you want to *filter* events for certain objects or you want to handle them without subclassing: what an event filter does is to intercept *any* event for a given target, then if you don't filter the event out, the target will receive it in its `event()` as explained above. So, just override `keyPressEvent()` and ensure that you call the base implementation *if* you don't handle the key.

Comment: There is no such "idiomatic" or "recommended" way. The correct approach will always be application-specific. As it stands, the question doesn't provide enough information to decide which one is most appropriate. Without more concrete details, it's merely a matter of opinion / coding-style which API is chosen.

Comment: @ekhumoro Do you have any particular details in mind which would help clarify the question?

Comment: @Pkkm Some have already been pointed out in other comments, as well as being quite clearly documented in [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent), [QKeyEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qkeyevent.html), [event](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#event), and [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter). There are also many examples on SO which show a basic implementation: e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207870/984421) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431365/984421). It's not complicated: just do the simplest thing that works for you.

Comment: @Pkkm Questions that ask for recommendations or best practices are generally off-topic on SO, because they tend to invite opinions rather than practical solutions. You should always write code *first* and then only post questions (including a [mre]) when you run into specific problems that you can't find answers to. At the moment, there's nothing in your question that points to any kind of real problem (other than some vaguely-worded concerns).

Comment: @Pkkm I will point out one design consideration that hasn't really been mentioned so far: the use of Qt Designer. If your UI design includes lots of line-edits that need special keyboard-handling, you may want to consider using [widget promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076247/984421) rather than an event-filter, since that provides an easy way to use a custom QLineEdit sub-class instead. But like I said above: it really all depends on the specific requirements of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the highly informative comments. My conclusion is that an event filter and a derived class each have one unique advantage: an event filter will work for both QLineEdit and QTextEdit, while a derived class will be easier to use with an external designer. The latter is more important to me, so I've decided to use a derived class. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make the question not open-ended, as my goal in asking it was precisely to get this kind of information about pros and cons that I haven't thought of.

Comment: @Pkkm As already pointed out, getting pros/cons isn't really the purpose of SO. We can provide solutions and then, *optionally* present pros and cons about them based on our own experiences, which may be completely different from your needs, but the primary objective is to get practical answers and eventually let the OP decide what's best for *their* needs (possibly after considering the opinion of each answer, but only after remembering that they are *opinions* of their authors and they are not to be considered as main part of the actual answer). There can always be a "better" (or worse) way.

Comment: @Pkkm for instance, you say that an event filter will work for both QLineEdit and QTextEdit, and ekhumoro correctly points out the usage of promotions. But there's also another similar possibility: using mixins. Consider a base `object` subclass that implements `keyPressEvent` and that can be used for multiple inheritance with *any* class (as long as it's properly implemented); if the function receives a `Key_B` key with a `ControlModifier`, it can create a synthetic `QKeyPress` event for a `Key_Left` key and call again `keyPressEvent()` with it, which will work with both editor types.

Comment: @Pkkm If the key combination isn't met, then just call the basic implementation using `super().keyPressEvent(event)`. Then, you'll only need to create a subclass for the actual widget using the proper inheritance; for example, assuming you created the above class as `EmacsKey`, then you just create a basic `class MyLineEdit(EmacsKey, QLineEdit): pass`. That's *one* possibility of many, and also one of the reasons for which open ended questions are normally frown upon: it may work for you, or not. But we should do the other way around: if it *does not* work for you, we can tell you why.